# What to call the "non-human" members of the animal kingdom?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I thought of the words *earlier* and *smaller*, but I think they are incorrect. Is there a way of referring to this kingdom and not include humans?

Example:

> The focus of the class shifted from humans to the [...] members of the
>   animal kingdom.

Comment: The focus of the class shifted from humans to the ***other*** members of the animal kingdom.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes, it's quite an interesting and valid question.

Comment: We generally distinguish between humans and animals. Although humans are technically animals, people tend not to think of it that way, at least in English. "You're an animal!" is used to tell someone he's behaving brutishly. And if you show someone a picture of a little girl with three puppies and three kittens and ask them "How many animals are in this picture?" you're most likely be told "six."

Comment: Well in my line of work I quite regularly refer, in the English language, to 'non-human animals'. I for one, would welcome a more concise and easy phrase if it's out there.

Comment: "The focus of the class shifted from humans to inferior species". (*If you don't consider man as the most inferior specie*).

Comment: @Graffito More specifically, if you consider Man the *supreme* species, and you want to communicate that partisanship to your readers (which might put off any of a scientific bent, who tend to balk applying such notions as a superior/inferior continuum to biology).

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either. The sentence was just to illustrate my word-request. And word-request even has a tag on this site.

Comment: @janoChen There is no accounting for taste. I don't start worrying about downvotes unless I get several of them, or someone gives me a good explanation for them (i.e. an explanation I agree with; if I don't agree with someone's complaint, I simply ignore it and its attendant downvote). Anyway, here, +1 gets you back to neutral.

Comment: @DanBron - To be neutral, "*other*" is perfect. I proposed "*inferior species*", because the question mentionned  "earlier" and "smaller".

Comment: You found it already: *non-human (members of the animal kingdom)*

Comment: (See [Animal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Animal).)

Comment: Andrew got it immediately. _Other_ is required when specifying _the Animal Kingdom_, which is a technical biological term. Consequently, since H. sapiens is a member of the Animal Kingdom, it's the ***other*** members who are being referred to. Anything else would be out of order with a technical biological term setting the context.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/618962/2085).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

...shifted to *other* species of ... or "to the *other* members of ..."

Comment: (I wrote the same answer, before I realized yours was present.)