# Word that means non-human animals?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, animals

Humans are animals.

The term "animals" is sometimes used to mean all animals (including humans) and is sometimes used to mean every animal except for humans.

Is there a word that means non-human animals?

Comment: English has no such precision.  A robot is *nonhuman*.  Most mammals are *sentient*.  And other terms will have similar deficiencies.  If you want to specify non-human animals you need to say so explicitly.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks.  You arent going to find something that exact.  You will have to provide context to eliminate humans.  "Man rose over the beasts of the Earth."  That context separates humans from all other animals.

Comment: @HotLicks : No, you don't. When I ask someone how many animals he has in his house, it's obvious what I mean. When I tell someone I went to the zoo to see animals, it's also obvious. If I was hiking and someone asks how many animals did I see, it's also obvious, and not one will misunderstand it, except for someone who deliberately does it to drive some agenda. The word "animal" is very commonly used in everyday speech, and nowhere except in more technical talk does it mean exactly the same as "metazoa".

Comment: I think you have said it yourself. "Animal" can be used to mean non-human animals in the right _context_. If you were at the zoo and someone said "look at all the animals," that would almost always mean the non-human animals.

Comment: @vsz I mostly agree with this, even though I wrote other answer below.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/277434/14073

Comment: @vsz - You miss the point.  *Because* the meaning of "animals" is, as you say, "obvious" in a given context, there is no need to have set terms that are precise (and, lacking such need, the terms don't exist).  Only if one demands that the usage be completely unambiguous, in spite of context (or the lack thereof), is it necessary to use explicit wording (in the form of a phrase of several words).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**"Wildlife"** could be used to differentiate between humans and non-human animals, but will not account for any non-human domesticated animals like dogs, cats, birds, etc.

From Merriam-Webster:

> living things and especially mammals, birds, and fishes that are neither human nor domesticated

Another option could be **"Fauna"** which describes the animals common in a particular region at a given time.

From Merriam-Webster:

> animal life; especially :  the animals characteristic of a region, period, or special environment

However, the definition does not specifically exclude humans. In common usage, "fauna" pertains to the "wildlife" ie. non-domesticated animals unless describing prehistoric human species/ancestors (which we could consider "non-domesticated"). If someone were to ask about the current fauna of America, I would assume they were looking for non-human, non-pet, native wildlife of the area.

Answer (score 44):

**"Beast"** is a bit biblical, perhaps, but it is commonly understood to mean non-human animals.

From Merriam-Webster:

> **Beast**: 1 a :  a four-footed mammal as distinguished from a human being, a lower vertebrate, and an invertebrate
>
> b :  a lower animal as distinguished from a human being

More clarification from the Oxford English Dictionary follows.  The omitted passage in the parenthetical (which is theirs) explains that *beast* was especially used in biblical translations for the similar concept from the Greek and Latin (confirming the source of the biblical flavor). The overall OED entry for *beast* also seems to confirm that the word is now mostly literary or antiquated for the broader sense argued for here, and it distinguishes from the literal and metaphorical senses when applied to man.

From OED:

> I. Literal senses. 
>   1. A living being, an animal. (Used to translate .... Now restricted in literary use as in sense 2, but still widely applied in dialect and colloquial use, including e.g. newts, insects, centipedes.)
>
> a. In early times, explicitly including man. Obs.
>
> b. In later times, applied to the lower animals, as distinct from man.

(Examples from published usage omitted here.)

Sense 2 (as referenced above, also from OED):

> 2. a. A quadruped (or animal popularly regarded as such), as distinguished from birds, reptiles, fishes, insects, etc., as well as from man. (Now the ordinary literary use.)

Additional senses (2b, 3, etc.) have to do with more specialized kinds of uses (animals as hunted, domesticated animals, etc.).

Comment: **Beasties** is also used.

Comment: The term *beast* is also applied to humans, men and women,  when their behaviour is considered especially deviant or inhumane. And, ironically, it can also be used a compliment

Comment: Beast has a lot of connotations that may not be appropriate, and I wouldn't necessarily assume that its use was meant to mean *everything but humans*.

Comment: From Psalms: "O LORD, You preserve man and beast."

Comment: While I think this is the best word for non-human animals, I wouldn't use it for a butterfly.

Comment: Indeed.  While this is probably the best option, it has a strong implication that excludes, for example, insects, fish, and other animal groups.  It may also imply an exclusion of primates, or at least those that have a strong resemblance of humans.  If these implications are a problem in context, then Tucker's suggetsion of "creature" is probably better, otherwise I would usually use this one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Absolutely, but there I would argue you are clearly using a metaphor. You are likening a human's behaviour or character to that of an animal, to that of a beast. In the way that cars and other inanimate objects could be called beasts and in the way that human beings can be called spanners, or doughnuts, or dogs, or mice

Comment: @Mari-Lou A, But in the sense that you are using it specifically means that a person is behaving unlike a human. If you say someone is a beast then you are saying that they are behaving like an animal, not a human.

Comment: it's very archaic.

Answer (score 38):

[Creature](https://www.google.co.in/#q=define+creature) - an animal, as distinct from a human being.

[Creature](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/creature) - 1. an animal, especially a nonhuman:

Comment: I've heard human women referred to as "a beautiful creature".

Comment: @dotancohen That's the wonderful thing about English is that you can bend meanings and apply them to another thing to emphasize it. "Sneaky as a fox." "Quick as a snake." Even using Brian's example: "He's a beast!" And so on and so forth...

Comment: I see. For what it's worth, the downvote wasn't mine.

Comment: @tucker that wonderful thing can be done with probably every language

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek Probably, but this SE is about English, so that's not necessarily relevant, just that it is true about English.

Comment: Using terms like _beast_ or _creature_ to refer to humans is generally metaphoric. That doesn't change the basic meanings of the words.

Comment: @ChristiaanWesterbeek - [Lojban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lojban) is the only one I can think of as a counterexample -- it has a specific grammatical marker for figurative expressions, so you would never confuse dotancohen's example for a literal use of "creature".

Answer (score 3):

The Latin 'fauna' is one option.
'Animals' does not include humans; 'animalistic' refers to behaviour that is sub-human in its character.
'Creatures' does however include humans as part of God's living Creation.

Comment: 'fauna' is not an option; 'fauna' means the variety and population of animals inside an environment, not a non-human animal.

Comment: As an animal, I disagree that animals does not include humans.

Comment: @DCShannon: on the internet no one knows you're <del>a dog</del> an animal

Answer (score -1):

From [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/brute) dictionary

> **brute**
>
> 1 A savagely violent man or animal
>
> 2 An animal as opposed to a human being

Comment: "A savagely violent man" man -> human